# ion-scroll horizontal is wrapping div boxes instead of scrolling them to the right

Tags: javascript, scroll, ionic-framework, horizontal-scrolling

this puts all the ion-items next to each, but then wraps them to the next line, instead of keeping them all on one line allow user to scroll horizontally. As a result, there is no scroll

I see the following

```
[1] [2] [3]
[4] [5] [6]
[7] [8] [9]
```

when I should be seeing:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9]
```

//

```
.horizontal-scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:1000px;
}
<ion-scroll direction="x" class="horizontal-scroll" scrollbar-x="false">
  <ion-item style="float:left" ng-repeat="otherRides in allRides" href="#/tab/others/{{others.ID}}">
    <img ng-src="{{others.icon}}" style="float:left">
      Time: {{others.time}}
      <br>Est: <span ${{others.price}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: well, I managed to get them all in a single row, but now that row won't scroll horizontally.  The `[4th]` item is half on the screen and half off...thus [5] thruh [9] aren't accessible without the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

the class can't be applied to the scroll itself the scroll applies to a container, adding the DIV between ion-scroll and ion-item did the trick. also added in `overflow-scroll="false"`.

I resolved it with the following:

```
.horizontal-scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:1000px;
}

<ion-scroll direction="x" scrollbar-x="false" overflow-scroll="false">
  <div class="horizontal-scroll">
    <ion-item style="float:left" ng-repeat="otherRides in allRides" href="#/tab/others/{{others.ID}}">
      <img ng-src="{{others.icon}}" style="float:left">
        Time: {{others.time}}
        <br>Est: <span ${{others.price}}
    </ion-item>
  </div>
</ion-scroll>
```